# How to cover up scratches on wood

Tags: home, furniture

A lot of the wooden furniture in my house has scratches on them and over time, they've gotten more and more visible. I've thought about painting over the scratches, but I don't know how good that would look and I don't have paint the color of the wood anyway. **How can I cover up scratches on wooden furniture using only things that I would have in my house?**

Comment: I have never seen anyone ask and answer so many of their own questions.  Is this an attempt to seed the site or do you just have lots of questions that you can't answer until you post them here?

Comment: @Minnow The site has not had too much traffic, so I am trying to seed the site. I also think that many of my Q&A's can be helpful to other people, so I just want to share what I know.

Comment: Cool, I agree your Q&A are both useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options for fixing scratches on wood

#### Small Scratches

- Use a walnut - break open a walnut, so its meat is exposed. Gently rub the walnut back and forth across the scratch. The oil will naturally fill in the scratched area
- Black Tea - put black tea bag in a cup and pour 2 or 3 tablespoons over it. Let it sit for 2-3 minutes; the longer it sits, the darker the color. Dip a cotton swab in the tea, then dab it on the scratch

#### Deep Scratches

- Get a wax stick that is the same color as the furniture (you can also blend different colors if you need to)
- Fill in the scratch until its slightly overfilled
- Scrape off the extra wax on top with a credit card or some other type of card
- Clean off any excess wax around the now filled-in scratch with a cloth or towel

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing to do is clean the area around the scratches so any method you use is more effective. If you have any steel wool or sandpaper, then you can use it to lightly rub against the grain of the wood to clean it up. Be careful or this method could actually cause more scratches.